# Помогите, составить регулярное выражение для проверки телефонного номера на валидность

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь составить регулярное выражение, и до конца не получается это сделать. Условия такие:

- номер должен начинаться с плюса
- в номере должно быть 12 цифр
- в номере может быть одна пара скобок
- если есть пара скобок, то между ними должно быть строго 3 цифры
- номер должен оканчиваться на цифру.

Вот что пока написал:

```
^\+\d{1,9}((\(\d{3}\))|\d{3})\d{1,9}$
```

Если после первой группы ставить что-то вроде `{12,14}`, то вообще не работает. Но не знаю, как ещё можно проверить, что в номере именно 12 цифр.

Получается должно проходить на следующих номерах: `+5(150)12345678`, `+123(123)123456`, `+12345678(123)1`

Неправильные номера: `+123456`, `12346`, `123(131)`, `+123(1)12345678`...

Comment: Может, `s.matches("\\+(?:\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d{9}|\\d{12})"`?

Comment: @Max Lich `^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$`

Comment: @Kromster стандарт позволяет содержать до пятнадцати цифр

Comment: Я так понимаю, что тупейшее перечисление всех возможных шаблонов: `\+\(\d{3}\)\d{9}|\+\d\(\d{3}\)\d{8}|\+\d{2}\(\d{3}\)\d{7}|\+\d{3}\(\d{3}\)\d{6}|\+\d{4}\(\d{3}\)\d{5}|\+\d{5}\(\d{3}\)\d{4}|\+\d{6}\(\d{3}\)\d{3}|\+\d{7}\(\d{3}\)\d{2}|\+\d{8}\(\d{3}\)\d|\+\d{12}` не нравится...

Comment: @Kromster по условию задачи так. Это учебное задание.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ваш способ не работает. Он не работает на строке +10(350)1234567

Comment: Вы вообще не привели никаких примеров, так что это у Вас не работает. Вопрос неясный.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ну по условию задачи должно быть понятно, какие номера подходят.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас добавлю номера, которые должны проходить

Comment: Телефонный номер обычно `+код_страны(код_сети)номер_абонента` `(код_сети)номер_абонента` 10 цифр с переменным количеством в скобках и вне скобок. Для мобильных сетей 3 цифры кода, 7 абонент. Для городских телефонных станций не помню какая традиция. Может тоже три и семь, может код сети забирает цифры из номера абонента. Код страны может достигать и трёх цифр. Больше не припомню.

Answer (score 6):

Для проверки валидности телефонного номера вам необходимо и достаточно удалить из него все нецифровые символы и убедиться в том, что результат соответствует необходимой длине (как минимум [не превышает 15 символов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164), исключая [префикс международной связи](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_international_call_prefixes)). Больше сделать вручную вы просто не можете; оперировать телефонными номерами при необходимости (отправка смс, автоматизированные звонки) вы будете в таком же виде - просто строкой, состоящей из цифр.

Проще всего взять [google libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) и пользоваться ей.

Comment: Если я тупо удалю из строки все нецифровые символы, тогда я не смогу проверить строку на валидность. Можно тогда проверить только на количество цифр.

Comment: @MaxLich вам же советуют старшие товарищи взять *libphonenumber* - выкиньте ваши регулярку на свалку. `regexp` это зло... То что умеет *libphonenumber* - вы никакой регуляркой не добьетесь.

Comment: Это понятно. Но мне нужно потренироваться в написании регулярных выражений. Начинаю с азов.

Comment: @MaxLich не увидел на момент написания вашего комментария о том, что это задание на регулярки

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать нечто такое:

```
\+\d{12}\b|\+\d{1}\(\d{3}\)\d{6}\b
```

[Ссылка](https://regex101.com/r/qJBj3X/2) на результат

Только почему 12? В номере же 11 символов, не считая `+`

Comment: нет, именно 12 должно быть. Так по заданию. Уже писал выше.

Comment: И тут ещё одно в Вашей регулярке. Перед скобками может быть сколько угодно цифр и после скобок тоже. Но в скобках должно быть строго 3 цифр. Ну и в итоге номер должен состоять именно из 12 цифр.

Comment: @MaxLich ну можно попробовать так `\+\d{12}\b|\+\d+\(\d{3}\)\d+`, но тогда мы не сможем проверить сколько чисел входит после окончния скобок

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за ответы. В итоге, оказалось, решить задачу, правда, можно и не обязательно с помощью одних только регулярок (а я думал, только их нужно использовать). То есть решил так: для начала проверяю строку (номер телефона) на общую валидность (чтобы не была пустая и не была нуллом), потом проверяю количество цифр в ней (всё средствами Джавы), а потом уже, в конце, использую регулярку.